# How to use a plugin method in the onDispatch event?

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-controller-plugin

I have a plugin which looks up the user grants.

I declarated it in my module.config.php as follows:

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\Plugin\AccessPlugin::class => function($container) {
            return new Controller\Plugin\AccessPlugin(
                $container->get(Model\UserTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\GrantsTable::class),
                $container->get(Model\Authentication::class)
                );
        },
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        'access' => Controller\Plugin\AccessPlugin::class,
    ]
],
```

In my `onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)` event I want to fetch the http routing parameters, look up the grant and, if successful, redirect to the correct route.

```
  public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {
            $controller = $event->getTarget();
            $controllerName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', null);
            $actionName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', null);
            $actionName = str_replace('-', '', lcfirst(ucwords($actionName, '-')));
            $this->access()->checkAccess($controllerName, $actionName);


....
```

Of course the plugin can't be find, it isn't loaded yet:

> Call to undefined method User\Module::access()

I'd like to call the plugin method anyway. Is there a possibility to use it in this case? Something like this:

```
        $grantplugin = fetch/call the plugin
        $isgranted = $grantplugin->checkAccess($controllerName, $actionName);
```

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:
I tried the solution ermengildo gave me. But it doesn't work, the reason is, that I haven't worked with factories yet. With a bit of help I can probably learn how to do it properly. Here my nippets:

I located the two services here:

[image: location of services]

I changed the module.php to (snippet!):

public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {

```
    $controller = $event->getTarget();
    $controllerName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', null);
    $actionName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', null);
    $actionName = str_replace('-', '', lcfirst(ucwords($actionName, '-')));
    $container = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $accessService = $container->get(Service\AccessControl::class);
    $accessService->access()->checkAccess($controllerName, $actionName);
```

Last I tried to declarate the service as a factory:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        // Avoid anonymous functions
        Service\AccessControl::class => Service\AccessControlFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Remark: Here already I have the syntax warning: 
...cannot be resolved to a type

If I debug, I get an exception:

> Unable to resolve service "User\Service\AccessControl" to a
>   factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

In the further explanation this line in my module.php shall be the problem:

```
 $accessService = $container->get(Service\AccessControl::class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that "the plugin hasn't been loaded yet", but that you are not inside a *controller*, and you are trying to call a *controller* plugin.

What you must do here is to create a service, retrive an instance from the service manager, and call the method on that instance.

Example

**module.config.php**

```php
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        // Avoid anonymous functions
        \User\Service\AccessControl::class => \User\Service\AccessControlFactory::class
    ]
]
```

**AccessControlFactory**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use User\Service\AccessControl;

class AccessControlFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    /**
     * Factory called
     *
     * @param \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container
     * @param string $requestedName
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return TranslatorPlugin
     */
    public function __invoke(\Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
        $userTable = $container->get(\User\Model\UserTable::class);
        $grantsTable = $container->get(\User\Model\GrantsTable::class);
        $authentication = $container->get(\User\Model\Authentication::class);
        return new AccessControl($userTable, $grantsTable, $authentication);

    }

}
```

**AccessControl**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use User\Model\UserTable;
use User\Model\GrantsTable;
use User\Model\Authentication;

class AccessControl {

    private $userTable;
    private $grantsTable;
    private $authentication;

    function __construct(UserTable $userTable, GrantsTable $grantsTable, Authentication $authentication) {
        $this->userTable = $userTable;
        $this->grantsTable = $grantsTable;
        $this->authentication = $authentication;

    }

    public function access(){
        // Do your stuff
    }

}
```

And finally, you can create it in your `Module` class and use it:

**User\Module**

```php
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event) {
    $controller = $event->getTarget();
    $controllerName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', null);
    $actionName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', null);
    $actionName = str_replace('-', '', lcfirst(ucwords($actionName, '-')));
    $container = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $accessService = $container->get(\User\Service\AccessControl::class);
    $accessService->access()->checkAccess($controllerName, $actionName);

}
```

## Side note

From your snippets, it is quite obvious what you are trying to achieve. I'd suggest you to take a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52832998/1842846), and at the comment done by rkeet, because that's the proper way to do access controls. ;)

Comment: I tried it, knowing nothing about factories, I'm leaving with errors. I'd really like to understand because I could use this technic also for other things. So I edited my post and supplied some snippets. could you be so kind to have a second look?

Comment: did you adapted the namespaces of the two classes?

Comment: I edited the code and added the `User` into the namespace. Keep in mind that this is an exemple, and not a "copy&paste&work", but it requires a bit of configuration, like choosing proper names, fixing namespaces, etc..

Comment: As I already suggested you in a previous question, there is a good explaination in the [Zend tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/), especially in the [Database and models section](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/)

Comment: There was one forgotten namespace Service; I adapted to namespace User\Service; That works now. Last I have trouble with this:  $authentication = $container->get(AuthenticationService::class); "unable to resolve service"

Comment: Yes,but I didn't understood everything in there. ;-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200892/discussion-between-ermenegildo-and-pia-sophie).